# Why is my pipe in Linux getting stuck?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I am shelling this:

```
mkfifo my_fifo
```

with this permission:

```
prw-r--r--
```

then I do:

```
echo this is my fifo > my_fifo
```

but it gets stuck and after ten seconds from another shell the size of `my_fifo` is zero.

Why is that?

Comment: Unless otherwise programmed, a fifo will block the writer while there is no reader. Once the data is consumed from the fifo the writer will be allowed to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal 1:

```
$ cat > my_fifo
```

In terminal 2:

```
$ cat my_fifo
```

After that type something in terminal 1 and check terminal 2.

Note about FIFO size: it is always 0 as it's not regular file, but named pipe which use RAM instead of disk.